# Is there an advantage for a central bank to not use a blend of private and public for its reserve bank system and make it fully public?

Tags: federal-reserve, central-bank

> Pursuant to the Federal Reserve Act, each of the 12 Reserve Banks is
> separately incorporated and has a nine-member board of directors.
> Commercial banks that are members of the Federal Reserve System hold
> stock in their District’s Reserve Bank and elect six of the Reserve
> Bank’s directors; three remaining directors are appoint- ed by the
> Board of Governors. Most Reserve Banks have at least one Branch, and
> each Branch has its own board of directors. Branch directors are
> appointed by either the Reserve Bank or the Board of Governors.
>
> Directors serve as a link between the Federal Reserve and the private
> sector. **As a group, directors bring to their duties a wide variety of
> experiences in the private sector, which gives them invaluable insight
> into the economic conditions of their respective Federal Reserve
> Districts. Reserve Bank head-office and Branch directors contribute to
> the System’s overall understanding of the economy.**
>
> The Federal Reserve is not funded by congressional appropriations. Its
> operations are financed primarily from the interest earned on the
> securities it owns—securities acquired in the course of the Federal
> Reserve’s open market operations. The fees received for priced
> services provided to depository institutions—such as check clearing,
> funds transfers, and automated clearinghouse op- erations—are another
> source of income; this income is used to cover the cost of those
> services. After payment of expenses and transfers to surplus (limited
> to an aggregate of $6.785 billion), all the net earnings of the
> Reserve Banks are transferred to the U.S. Treasury (figure 1.4)

https://www.federalreserve.gov/aboutthefed/files/the-fed-explained.pdf

> From 1952 to 1955 government shares were added to private banks to
> make state-private banks, until under the first Five Year plan from
> 1955 to 1959 the PBC had complete control of the private banks, making
> them branches of the PBC, closely resembling the vision of Vladimir
> Lenin.[citation needed] With aid from the Soviet Union, the shares of
> private enterprises and with them industrial output followed a similar
> path, forming a Soviet-style planned economy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Bank_of_China

According to the Federal Reserve itself, the reserve banks in the U.S. are a blend of private and public organizations, but in China, it seems that they fully made them public. The reason they give for using a blend of private and public is in order to get a deeper insights on the macroeconomic situation. Is there an advantage for a central bank to not use a blend of private and public for its reserve bank system and make it fully public?